# Cannot resolve all property references in the property path with attached property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, storyboard

i'm struggling with setting attached properties out of a different project in a storyboard with xaml.

In the style of a textbox i have an eventtrigger which should set an attached property to true after an event.

XAML:

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:Project.Utilities"

<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SomeEvent">
   <BeginStoryboard>
      <Storyboard>
         <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="MyNamespace:MyClass.MyAttachedProperty">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
         </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
   </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

C#:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public static class MyClass
   {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty MyAttachedPropertyProperty
         = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyAttachedProperty", typeof(bool), 
           typeof(MyClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

      public static void SetMyAttachedProperty(DependencyObject target, bool value)
      {
        target.SetValue(MyAttachedPropertyProperty, value);
      }

      public static bool GetMyAttachedProperty(DependencyObject target)
      {
        return (bool)target.GetValue(MyAttachedPropertyProperty);
      }
   }
}
```

With the PropertyPath I did it like discribed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520709/set-custom-attached-property-on-storyboard).
But I always get an 'System.InvalidOperationException' with:
Additional information: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'MyNamespace:MyClass.MyAttachedProperty'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

I tried several different ways to write the path with parenthesise and without them but honestly I don't quite get it how the path has to be defined it even not with the help of the [MSDN Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx)

Does anyone has an idea what else I could try to access the attached property?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <animation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ownerType.propertyName)" .../>

Answer (score 2):

From the Attached Property section of the English version of the page that you linked to, [Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#attacheddata):

#### Attached Property

```
<object Path="...(ownerType.propertyName)..." ... />
```

> The parentheses indicate that this property in a PropertyPath should be constructed using a partial qualification because it needs late-binding context information, such as the type being applied to for applied templates. **It can use a prefix usage for a XAML namespace to find the type. The ownerType searches types that a XAML processor has access to, based on xmlns mappings (or using the default XAML namespace if unqualified).** propertyName must resolve to the name of a property that exists on the ownerType.

I have highlighted a section that says that you *can* use a prefix, so that would turn the example into this:

```
<object Path="...(namespacePrefix:ownerType.propertyName)..." ... />
```

Further on at the bottom of the linked page, there is a community addition from Raphael Schweizer:

> > #### Property Path for Custom DP in Animation does not work
> >
> > It should be noted that the Property Path syntax for attached properties works only with the MS attached properties but not for
> >     Custom attached properties.
> >
> > #### Answer
> >
> > Custom attached properties can be used
> >
> > • XAMLPath = (Namespace:CustomOwner.AttachedProperty)

If you tried this and it *didn't* work, then you have a problem elsewhere in your code.